# Multer: Unexpected field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

Im trying to create a api that accepts images for my projects, but for some reason it gives the folowing error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>MulterError: Unexpected field<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.emit (events.js:310:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at PartStream.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at PartStream.emit (events.js:310:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:310:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SBMH.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SBMH.emit (events.js:310:20)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SBMH._sbmh_feed (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:95:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SBMH.push (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:56:14)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at HeaderParser.push (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:46:19)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at Dicer._oninfo (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:197:25)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at SBMH.&lt;anonymous&gt; (C:\Users\Usuário\Desktop\dicionario\backend\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:127:10)</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

here is my code

```
const multer = require('multer')
const uploads = multer({dest: 'uploads/'})


router.post('/', uploads.single('ImagemSinal') ,async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file)
    try{
        const { title, description, tasks } = req.body

        const project =  await Project.create({title, description, user: req.userId });

       await Promise.all(tasks.map( async task => {
            const projectTask = new Task({...task, project: project._id})

           await projectTask.save()

           project.tasks.push(projectTask)
        }))

        await project.save()
        return res.send({ project })
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
        return res.status(400).send({error: 'Error creating new project'})
        
       
    }
})
```

and thats how im doind the request in postman

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send the image from Postman, you have to type `ImagemSinal` as `keyValue` for image, because you specified that in the server side.

You can also change code in the Server side and instead of `uploads.single('ImagemSinal')` you can type `uploads.any()`.

Comment: it kinda works, but now i have to solve other bugs that apeared hahahaha,

Comment: Or you can just type in Postman `ImagemSinal` as an `keyValue`.

Comment: This works with `app.use(multer(config).any())`, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just type file as the key value, should work now. Worked for me